# MySQL: how do I do in inline function with ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql

So, I want to create a formula for ordering things by popularity, but I don't want to create a stored procedure or function. I'd like the function just to be in my query.

So, is there a way to do something like

```
SELECT cols
FROM tables
WHERE conditions
ORDER BY function(){ logic using cols } DESC LIMIT 10
```

or something like that?

Comment: What does the logic look like?

Comment: How is the popularity determined?

Comment: haven't figured that out yet. but it will do math on three different columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to create a stored procedure or function

You want to call a function but you don't want to define a function?  Okay...

You can use expressions in the ORDER BY clause, including [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) which is pretty powerful:

```
SELECT cols
FROM tables
WHERE conditions
ORDER BY CASE WHEN col1 BETWEEN a AND b THEN 1 
              WHEN col1 BETWEEN c AND d THEN 2
              ...
         END
     DESC LIMIT 10
```

But it's often easier to do the calculation in your select-list and then order by that calculated column:

```
SELECT cols, POW(col1, col2) AS calc1
FROM tables
WHERE conditions
ORDER BY calc1 DESC LIMIT 10
```